# Does Convert.ChangeType Shortcut?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering what happens inside `Object Convert.ChangeType( Object object, Type type)` when the type of `object` matches `type`. Does it just short-cut and return `object`?

For example:

```
object objString = "Hello World";

string converted = (string) Convert.ChangeType( objString, typeof ( String ) );
```

Would the implementation of `ChangeType` actually call the `IConvertible` interface or just return objString?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's C# reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,3bcca7a9bda4114e), `Convert.ChangeType(Object, Type)` performs the following general behaviour:

- If the input is null

  - If the type is a value type, throw.
  - Otherwise return null.
- If the input is not `IConvertible`

  - If the type is exactly the input's type, return the input.
  - Otherwise throw.
- If the type is one of the out-of-the-box core convertible types, call the corresponding `ToWhatever` method on the input.

  - In each case, the implementation seems to be `return this` if the types match or `return Convert.ToWhatever(this)` otherwise, which is a shortcut of sorts.
- Otherwise call `ToType` on the input, passing the type through.

Comment: Is this the same as `Convert.ChangeType`?

Comment: Whoops, I meant `ChangeType`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it would call IConvertible interface on the object.
In case of string it would call objString.ToString() which in turn would return itself (return this).

In addition, if type of object does not implement IConvertible and you convert to the same type then it will just return the same object.

If type does not implement IConvertible and you convert to different type then exception will be thrown.

Comment: Ok, but string was just an example. How about for `Int64`.

Comment: same thing: Convert.ChangeType(myInt64, typeof(Int64)) calls myInt64.ToInt64(myInt) returns myInt64

Comment: From reflector, it looks like for the core `IConvertible` implementors, `X.ToY()` is implemented as `return Convert.ToY(this)`, _except_ where `X == Y`, where it is instead implemented as `return this`. So it does shortcut to _that_ degree.

Comment: Thanks @Rawling, I think that's the answer I was after.

Answer (score 0):

[This MSDN blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/irenak/archive/2006/04/26/584087.aspx) might help you.

> If the class implements IConvertable interface, you can then use
>   System.Convert.ChangeType to change the data type:

```
decimal x = (decimal) System.Convert.ChangeType("5", typeof(decimal));
```

> Think of ChangeType as a big switch statement (select case in VB)… 
>   with lots of overloaded functions.  Something like this (disclaimer:
>   this is intended to be a pseudo-code, not the exact .NET’s
>   implementation):

```
public static Object ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode , IFormatProvider provider)
{

IConvertible v = value as IConvertible;

switch (typeCode) {

case TypeCode.Boolean:
    return v.ToBoolean(provider);

case TypeCode.Char:
    return v.ToChar(provider);

case TypeCode.SByte:
    return v.ToSByte(provider);

case TypeCode.Byte:
    return v.ToByte(provider);

case TypeCode.Int16:
    return v.ToInt16(provider);

case TypeCode.UInt16:
    return v.ToUInt16(provider);

. . .

}
```

> A class that claims to implement IConvertible interface must implement
>   all the conversions in the switch structure above plus GetTypeCode:
>
> ·          GetTypeCode
>
> ·          ToBoolean
>
> ·          ToByte
>
> ·          ToChar
>
> ·          ToDateTime
>
> ·          ToDecimal
>
> ·          ToDouble
>
> ·          ToInt16
>
> ·          ToInt32
>
> ·          ToInt64
>
> ·          ToSByte
>
> ·          ToSingle
>
> ·          ToString
>
> ·          ToType
>
> ·          ToUInt16
>
> ·          ToUInt32
>
> ·          ToUInt64
>
> System.Convert class has a number of implementations that can be, in
>   turn, called by the class implementing IConvertible interface.